# Most accessible field for undergraduate independent research

Tags: soft-question, research

I am studying in Europe as a mathematics undergraduate and I would like to start my own independent research in pure mathematics.
I do not expect to find a field in which I would be able to prove new results using only the limited knowledge acquired from
the lectures I have attended; none the less I suspect that some fields would require more backround knowledge than others, for example I have read multiple
posts from students interested in number theory with answers that point out the great gap between the theoretical background needed to tackle the subject
at the collage level and reasearch level. I am genuinely interested in solving problems just for the fun of it, so I think that my best option is to simply
find a field with relatively light prerequisites and start from some non-famous open problems there. The point of this whole endeavour is to familiarize myself with
the research process, not necessarily contribute to it; that would be a nice bonus. To wrap it up, I would like some suggestions regarding the field to pick - the one you think is most accessible to undegraduate students.

Comment: I think this falls under a polling question which is defined as off-topic in the [advice tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have removed the tag.

Comment: Have you ever studied algebras? It is a large field of every complexity you wish and has a lot of unknown questions. E.g., I could immediately tell you a subject in the theory of Lie algebras that nobody (except me) investigated, yet, and which is quite easy to start with. However, you should probably better know the basics. This is only one part among many other algebras. Here is an overview:
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/introduction-to-the-world-of-algebras/

Comment: Personally I think computability theory and model theory are relatively easy to pick up in terms of background knowledge required. Though I’m not sure if everyone will agree with that statement…